# A "Windows Explorer" Type Interface in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, controls, explorer

Does anyone know of a third party control or set of code that allows directory browsing integrated into a web page that uses master pages? So I'd need a content control that I can simply give a local server directory to as a root directory and it will display any files and directories in the browser underneath the root.

I don't need any upload support but download support is ideal.

Looking for something relatively cheap - ideally less than $300 - the cheaper the better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at telerik RadControls, and especially the [FileExplorer](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx) control.

It's not exactly "cheap", but the controls suite is very powerful.

Comment: As an interesting side note, online backup provider Carbonite uses the RadFileExplorer to power their online remote file access interface. If you're a Carbonite user, you can check it out online.